# How to delete rows that contain only certain values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, delete-row

I have a dataframe like this

```py
    column_name 
0   OnePlus phones never fail to meet my expectatiion.  
1   received earlier than expected for local set.   
2   \n  
3   good    
4   must buy!
5   \t
6     
7   awesome product!  
8     \n
```

I want to remove all rows which contain ONLY `\n`, `\t`,   , `\n` in them.

Output should be like this:

```py
    column_name 
0   OnePlus phones never fail to meet my expectatiion.  
1   received earlier than expected for local set.   
2   good    
3   must buy!
4   awesome product!
```

I tried the following method:

```py
  df = df[df.column_name != '\n'].reset_index(drop=True)
  df = df[df.column_name != ''].reset_index(drop=True)
  df = df[df.column_name != ' '].reset_index(drop=True)
  df = df[df.column_name != '   '].reset_index(drop=True)
  df = df[df.column_name != ' \n '].reset_index(drop=True)
```

But is there a more **elegant way or a pythonic way** to do this instead of repeating the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and compare only empty strings:

```
df1 = df[df.column_name.str.strip() != ''].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or convert empty values to boolean:

```
df1 = df[df.column_name.str.strip().astype(bool)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or filter words, for me was necessary `strip` (maybe in real data `strip` should be removed):

```
df1 = df[df.column_name.str.strip().str.contains('\W', na=False)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

If need remove missing values and no string values replace these values to `NaN`s and then use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df.column_name = df.column_name.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
df1 = df.dropna(subset=['column_name']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! The last one is more general, that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use [df.str.contains()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to check if there is any small alpha after forward slash

```
df[df.Column Name.str.contains('[\\][a-z]+',case=True, na=False, regex=True)]
```

In your case, Data:

```
print(pd.DataFrame({'A':['OnePlus phones never fail to meet my expectatiion','received earlier than expected for local set.','\n','good','\t', np.nan,'must buy!','','awesome product!','\n' ]}))

                                               A
0  OnePlus phones never fail to meet my expectatiion
1      received earlier than expected for local set.
2                                                 \n
3                                               good
4                                                 \t
5                                                NaN
6                                          must buy!
7                                                   
8                                   awesome product!
9                                                 \n
```

Solution

```
print(df[df.A.str.contains('[\\][a-z]+',case=True, na=False, regex=True)])



                             A
0  OnePlus phones never fail to meet my expectatiion
1      received earlier than expected for local set.
3                                               good
6                                          must buy!
8                                   awesome product!
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, removing rows where the entries match the flagged elements:

```
df = df[~df['column_name'].isin(['\\n','\\t'])].dropna()
```

If there are extra spaces in the last row (or others) you can first do:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.strip()
```